# Devo fazer o commit do arquivo .gitignore?

Tags: git

Uma dúvida que tenho quando começo projetos é:

Devo fazer o commit do arquivo `.gitignore`?

Em caso afirmativo, qual seria a sua função? Manter a padronização num projeto compartilhado?

Comment: Nem precisa ser questão de compartilhamento. Só de omitir binários compilados e outros que não seja necessário versionar, como por exemplo configurações de ambiente, para o próprio desenvolvedor se organizar ele já está sendo útil.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim, tu deves "commitar" o `.gitignore` a fim de que todos que usem o repositório não subam os arquivos que devem ser ignorados - como, por exemplo, binários gerados pela compilação dos projetos, ou configurações específicas que podem alterar de máquina para máquina (configuração da IDE, temas que tu gostas de usar, etc).

[Nesse link](https://www.atlassian.com/br/git/tutorials/saving-changes/gitignore) tu podes ver mais detalhes sobre como usar o `.gitignore`.